# FabricJS loadfromJSON does not render all objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

Trying to load canvas with JSON saved in backend for multiple screens.
clearing canvas before loading using             `canvas.clear();`

but though i can see object with length 5 renders only 2 objects.
acts randomly. sometime renders all sometimes partially.

```
   `canvas.loadFromJSON(json, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object) {
        console.log('rendered successfully')
        console.log(o,object)
        // `o` = json object
        // `object` = fabric.Object instance
        // ... do some stuff ...
    });`
```

not sure what's the issue.

sample Object:[enter link description here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.01ce1928ca724b7db5ef2b2da9b54850&right=cloud.93c0f5d8dc2a485dafe517146dfc472d)

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting JSON using canvas.toJSON() That will export its all available objects.

> BUT only canvas.toJSON() will not export many of properties like prototype, hasControl, meta etc.

> If you have used custom objects or prototypes to modify default object or create new type those will not export and import with only toJSON.

YOU have to use it like this in my case I wanted to export extra properties and so.

> 

```
        canvas.toJSON(['lockMovementX', 
        'lockMovementY', 
        'lockRotation', 
        'lockScalingX', 
        'lockScalingY', 
        'lockUniScaling',
        'hasBorders',
        'hasControls',
        'targetFindTolerance',
        'perPixelTargetFind',
        'selectable',
        'meta',
        'id',
        'prototype'
    ]
    )
```

This will be exporting my JSON objects + given attributes.